# Redirect stdin stdout to multiple files

Tags: unix, tcsh

i am using tcsh shell,
I am trying to write two files concurrently with same output.
One file the stdout will send to the start of the file
and the second file stdout will send to the end of file.
I have tried doing this

./something  2>&1 | tee log1.txt  1>  log2.txt

Just log1.txt has the STDOUT data

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Koby

Answer (score 2):

You should simply call:

`./something | tee file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`

**EDIT**: Ugly fix to append/prepend

`./something | tee -a file1.txt | cat - file2.txt > tmp && mv tmp file2.txt`

Comment: Hi,this will cause One file the stdout will send to the start of the file
and the second file stdout will send to the end of file?

Comment: The solution is to do it on two commands : first Generate file1.txt and second to copy the content of file1.txt to file2.txt